# Using Firebase rewrites to route /api/** to function and everything else to single page app

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I've seen other stack overflow answers for using Firebase rewrites to route /api/** to their Express app function.

I'm following those instructions, but also trying to host a single page app.

Combining the two doesn't seem to work as the API routes are getting mapped to my index.html file still.

These are my rewrites

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/api/**",
    "function": "api"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you post your Express function code?

Comment: Use a rewrite when you want to show the same content for multiple URLs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, i've managed to do it by excluding /api/ from the single page app rules.

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/api/**",
    "function": "api"
  },
  {
    "source": "!/api/**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Here we say :

- Everything that start with "/api/" goes to the function named "api"
- Everything else goes to your single page app (index.html)